# Link Table to Form

Tags: microsoft-access-2003

I've created a custom form in Design view in Access 2003. I cannot remember how to make the fields "see" my designed table. How do I do this? I know it has something to do with control source but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it... Properties of Form in design view (right click in blank spot, not in form); change "Record Source" to the specified table/query.

Then adjust control fields accordingly.